# How to calculate column sums in R and then plot it using data.table library

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

So I have my first job as a data analyst however my boss wants me to use the `data.table` package and I'm having some issues with it.

My data set is about e-commerce shops with total purchases and returns(client returns). I want to visualize in a barplot how many items were returned per product denoted as `Product name` (I know having spaces in column names is a bit odd, I will change it later) so my code is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

mainTable <- fread('returnStats.csv')  

essentialReturnData <- mainTable[,c(7,9)]

returnsByProductName <- essentialReturnData[, 
                                            .(totalReturns = sum(essentialReturnData$`Return quantity`)), 
                                            by = 'Product name']

barplot(table(returnsByProductName$`Product name`))
```

However, I'm only getting a data.table with with the same sum value for all the `Product name`s showed in the image below:

[image]

Then of course I'm having a barplot that looks like complete garbage:

[image]

Comment: `sum(essentialReturnData$\`Return quantity\`)` ignores the `by` grouping, since you're taking the sum in a different instance of the table. Use `sum(\`Return quantity\`)` instead.

Comment: Thanks! that worked! However, any ideas on how to improve my visualization? I want to show the product name on the x-axis, then the amount of returns on y-axis, when I use the ```barplot()``` function it returns a very bad plot

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed. The status message says the problem is not reproducible, or was caused by typos, and neither of those is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things wrong here:

1. Since you're asking for `` sum(essentialReturnData$`Return quantity`) ``, which is a call to a different instance of the table, the sum is ignoring the `by` grouping. Use `` sum(`Return grouping`) `` instead, since this refers to the column within the same instance of the table.
2. `` table(returnsByProductName$`Product name`) `` is a frequency table for the product names, but `returnsByProductName` only has one row per name. You're not using the `totalReturns` at all! Use `` barplot(returnsByProductName$totalReturns, names.arg = returnsByProductName$`Product name`) `` instead.

Given how many products you have, you'll have problems fitting all the names on the axis in a nice way. You can do things like adding a `las = 2` argument, which is passed to `par()` and makes the x-axis labels vertical. It's still going to look messy with that many products, however, and if the names are long then it doesn't leave much space for the plot itself, unless you make the plot size enormous.

Comment: Thank you very much, not just for the answer but also for the explanation! Everything makes sense now